# Elm: How do you log a function body?

Tags: elm

If I log a function:

```
Debug.log "List.foldl" (toString List.foldl)
<function> : a -> a
```

I get its function signature. How do I get the body of the function?

Answer (score 2):

[Debug.log](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/latest/Debug) takes two arguments: string and any variable. Both of them will be printed out and first paramenter should be used as a simple description what you are sending to logs.

In your case it could be:

```
Debug.log "List.foldl func" <| List.foldl
<function>
    : (a -> b -> b) -> b -> List a -> b
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm wondering if theres any way to log the actual function body though?

Comment: I don't think so. If you want to dig into source code you have to browse repository: https://github.com/elm-lang/core/blob/5.1.1/src/List.elm#L144-L155